# RemoveClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

We have a alert bar for when it shows or any other emergencies on campus. The problem is that the new website's home page drop down menu is open by default and covers up the alert bar when it is active. Here is the code that opens it:

```
// Show menu on homepage
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= 30 && $('body').hasClass("homepage") && $body.width() > 768 ) {
        $('body').addClass('sub-open');
    }

   $(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= 30 && $('body').hasClass("homepage") && $body.width() > 768 ) {
            $('body').addClass('sub-open');
        } else if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 30 && $('body').hasClass("homepage")) {
            $('body').removeClass('sub-open');
            $('.drop-wrap').css('display','none');
        }
   });
```

We have the option to add script in the CMS for pages but the scripts.js loads last and keeps overwriting the removeClass code. Is there a way to add code that closes the menu when the alert is active or a way to add code through the CMS thats order of execution is last. I hope that was clear and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the CSS so that either

1. They aren't on top of each other or..
2. The z-index of the alert bar is higher.

instead of messing around with script.

Answer (score 0):

You should definetely get into CSS and add this to the alert div

```
z-index: 999999;
```

This will place the alert on top of everything else in your website, therefore the menu won't come over it.

Also if you didn't take the time to go over the script, you shouldn't go around poking it with a stick, it might poke back. :)

Hope this helps